# Looking for study/genome data for HIV in different organs

Tags: dna-sequencing, database, sequence-analysis, hiv

I am looking for a research study or data base that has HIV genome data available in fasta or similar format. Specifically I need genome data of HIV taken from different organs in the same subject. I am interested in studying the way HIV diversifies and changes to infect different organs and in comparing the process across different patients.

If you are familiar with such a study, or if you have general pointers as to where I may find similar data, I would appreciate it very much. I have done a few hours of searching on NCBI GeneBank, but have had no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be better of migrating to [Bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website comes to my mind

https://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/index

It is a HIV databases containing HIV sequence data and related immunologic information